# How can I disable mail server in Mac OSX 10.6.8?

Tags: email, mac-osx

I am running MAMP Pro on my machine with all empty Postfix values. Yet, whenever my PHP application calls mail(), mail is being sent out from my machine. In a production environment this would be fine but I am in a development environment. [how can i disable outbound mail in postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/271260/how-can-i-disable-outbound-mail-in-postfix) discusses setting the default_transport = error. However, this setting does not appear in /private/etc/postfix/main.cf, additionally, I cannot verify that this is infact what I need. I want to be absolutely sure that mail is disabled. I do want to be able to receive mail from my Entourage client but that's it.

Can anyone help?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as described in the provided link. If the line is not present in `main.cf` then add a line with `default_transport = error:This server sends mail only locally.`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain what that means? "This server sends mail only locally"? I assume this means that I can send and retrieve mail only from and to myself but I want to be sure.

Comment: @Noor This is only the reply message. You could even write `error:Ha ha. I don't like sending mail. Don't try again`